# using $past in cover property statement

Tags: system-verilog

I have the following simple code:

```
module past;
  logic clk=0;
  logic[3:0] adr=0;

  // Clock Gen
  initial forever #10 clk = ~clk;
  initial #100 $finish;

  always @(posedge clk) adr <= adr+1;

  sequence DUMMY_SEQ;
    @(posedge clk) 1'b1;
  endsequence

  cover property (@(posedge clk) DUMMY_SEQ) begin
    $display("ADR %h past(ADR) %h at %0t", adr, $past(adr), $time);
  end
endmodule
```

I would expect the `$past(adr)` return the value of `adr` in previous **one** clock cycle. But I got below simulation result which seemingly the `$past(adr)` return the value of `adr` in previous **two** clock cycle. Please notice it from line number 3.

```
ADR 1 past(ADR) 0 at 10
ADR 2 past(ADR) 0 at 10
ADR 3 past(ADR) 1 at 10
ADR 4 past(ADR) 2 at 10
ADR 5 past(ADR) 3 at 10
```

Can anybody explain why it is behaving like that?
Just to be clear, I am using `$display` just for illustration purpose. The actual problem is I couldn't get correct `$past(adr)` in cover statement.

Lets forget about the `$display` and do something else in cover statement. For example, by right, `adr - $past(adr)` should never exceed 1 as per above code. If I do something like this:

```
cover property (@(posedge clk) DUMMY_SEQ) begin
  if ( (adr > $past(adr)) 
       && (adr - $past(adr)) > 1) $fatal;
end
```

then it should never get fatal, because `adr` increment by 1 at each clock cycle. However, it actually does get fatal error. This is confusing. Any explanation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you are seeing is `addr` is updated before the `$display` statement and `$past`. This gives the impression that `$past` looks two clocks behind. To resolve this, use `$sampled`. See [IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) 16.9.3 *Sampled value functions*

```
cover property (@(posedge clk) DUMMY_SEQ) begin
  $display("ADR %h past(ADR) %h at %0t", $sampled(adr), $past(adr), $time);
end
```

Output

```
ADR 0 past(ADR) 0 at 10  
ADR 1 past(ADR) 0 at 30  
ADR 2 past(ADR) 1 at 50  
ADR 3 past(ADR) 2 at 70  
ADR 4 past(ADR) 3 at 90
```

Another option is to put the display as a `sequence_match_item` which is best explained in [IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) 16.10 *Local variables*

```
cover property (@(posedge clk) (DUMMY_SEQ, $display("ADR %h past(ADR) %h at %0t", adr, $past(adr), $time));
```

For fatal and error reporting, it is better to use `assert`:

```
assert property (@(posedge clk) (adr >= $past(adr)) else $fatal;
```

Answer (score 1):

$past returns the value of an expression in a previous clock cycle.

Actually, there is difference between $display and $monitor that you have to understand.

$display displays once every time code is executed.
$monitor displays every time one of its parameters changes.

If you replace $display with $monitor then you will get your expected output.

Comment: That is my intention - I want to access the current and past value after the sequence is executed.

Comment: But, in $display will show values at only posedge of clk, Where $monitor shows values once parameter is changed.And your expectation $past returns value of adr in previous clock cycle. That will returns value in previous clock cycle but you can see that with a help of $monitor only not with a $past.

Comment: Actually my problem has nothing to do with `$display` or `$monitor`. I just couldn't get `$past` value correctly. I have editted my post, so that you may understand clearly my point.

Comment: Do not use `$monitor` like this. `$monitor` starts an independent thread that triggers itself when there is a change to a signal.  By putting it in a repeatably called procedural block, you are killing the old thread and creating a new thread every execution. Instead of `$monitor`, use `$strobe` which is executes in the same region in the verilog/SV scheduler.

Comment: Yes, $strobe is perfect for this rather than $monitor